# Почему не работает валидация над объектами типа DTO , а только над сущностями

Tags: java, spring-boot, nhibernate, bean-validation

У меня установлена аннотация над объектами типа **dto**, такая же как и над объектами типа **Entity**.
Над **сущностями** аннотация срабатывает, а над объектами типа **dto** - нет.

Работаю в **SrpingBoot**.

**application.properties**

```
# ===============================
# NAME_TABLE
# ===============================

validate.packageid.size = "The field 'PACKAGEID' can contain only {max} symbols.";
```

**Конфигурационный файл**

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {



    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        source.setBasename("classpath:ValidationMessages");
        return source;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return validator;
    }

}
```

**dto**

```
@Size(message = "{validate.packageid.size}", max = 36)
    private String documentId;
```

**entity**

```
 @Column(name = "DOCUMENTID")
    @Size(message = "{validate.packageid.size}", max = 36)
    private String documentId;
```

Я не в контроллере их заполняю, я работаю с тестами и заполняю эти **dto** с помощью рефлексии.

Если бы это был контроллер, тогда аннотация **@Valid** указывала бы на то, что прежде чем передать разобранный **json** в **dto**, то нужно произвести валидацию.

У меня вот так наполняется **dto**

```
 /*подготовка объекта на сохранение*/
 private DTO prepareDto(String uuid){

    DTO dto = fillObjectData(new DTO ());

    dto.setPackageId(uuid);

    return dto;
}
```

---

```
 /**
     * Формируется объект с заполненными полями
     * @param source - объект, который нужно заполнить случайными значениями
     * @param <T> - тип целевого объекта который нужно вернуть с заполенными значениями
     */
    public static  <T> T fillObjectData(T source) {

        List<Object> values = new ArrayList<>();

        T dto;

        dto  = fillData(source, values);

        getData(dto, values);

        return dto;

    }
```

---

```
  /**
     *  Заполнение полей объекта.
     * @param object - обрабатываемый объект, любого типа данных
     * @param values - коллекция значений, которые будут сгенерированы для полей обрабатываемого объекта
     * @param <S> - универсальный параметр, указывает на тип данных передаваемого объекта
     * @return  - возвращает обработанный объект. S - универсальный параметр, хранит информацию об текущем
     *            обрабатываемом объекте
     */
    public static  <S> S fillData (S object, List<Object> values){

        return obtainMetadataOfObject(object, values);
    }


    /**
     * Извлечение метаданных из полученного объекта, для дальнейшей обработки
     * @param object - обрабатываемый объект
     * @param values - коллекция значений, которые будут сгенерированы для полей обрабатываемого объекта
     * @param <S> - универсальный параметр, указывает на тип данных передаваемого объекта
     * @return - возвращает обработанный объект. S - универсальный параметр, хранит информацию об текущем
     * обрабатываемом объекте
     */
    private static <S> S obtainMetadataOfObject(S object, List<Object> values){

        Class<?> objectClass = object.getClass();

        Class superClazz = objectClass.getSuperclass();

        String nameObjectClass = "Object";

        String simpleNameObjectExpected = superClazz.getSimpleName();

        boolean isObjectClass = Objects.equals(simpleNameObjectExpected, nameObjectClass);


        if(!isObjectClass){

           return manageParseListArrFields( object, values, objectClass);
        }

        return manageParseArrFields( object, values, objectClass);

    }
.......
```

" .. Если бы это был контроллер, тогда аннотация @Valid указывала бы на то, что прежде чем передать разобранный json в dto, то нужно произвести **валидацию** .. " -  Я наполняю объект **dto** с помощью рефлексии и  аннотация **@Valid**, в методах где используется рефлексия и разбираются поля объекта, - не работает.

Здесь не применим подход, когда используется **@Valid** при обработке запроса в **rest**-контроллере и где эта аннотация ставиться в параметрах метода, обрабатывающего запрос

Возможно, из-за того, что **сущность** имеет аннотацию , согласно которой Spring при инициализации Application сontext создал **bean** данного класса. А в случае с dto, валидация происходит в момент, когда контроллер обрабатывает запрос, чтобы передать данные из json в dto-объект и в момент передачи данных, аннотация @Valid указывает на то, что нужно обратиться к полям, которые имееют аннотации-ограничения и провалидировать добавляемые данные.

Но в моем случае, данные в dto добавляются в тестовых методах.

**Oбновление (частичное решение)**

Нужно указать аннотацию **@Validated**. Эта аннотация от Spring и тогда Spring при обращение к объектам типа **dto** (на уровне бизнес-логики) валидирует
добавление значений.

Но это не работает почему то для объекта, который разделен на несколько классов. Хотя такого рода объект (уровень **dao** - где сущности расположены) валидируется спокойно, но там уже **Hibernate** управляет этим процессом.

Я же не использую клиента.

Я написал тесты, которые проверяют создание записи в таблицу, обращаясь на сервис-слой.

На сервис-слое я формирую объект с помощью рефлексии, чтобы 30 полей не собирать вручную. Я поставил проверку на аннотацию **Size**, чтобы вытянуть размер ограничения. И хоть я поставил аннотацию @**Validated**, я не получаю нужных данных.
@**Validated** хорошо работает для отдельных классов, но у меня таблица разбита на несколько *абстрактных* и один *производный* и хоть над ними стоят аннотации @**Validated** , в этом случае Spring не видит что нужно валидировать данные поля.

Не срабатывает **validation** для **DTO**, почему ?

Comment: Покажите контроллер с методами, где вы получаете DTO и/или сущностями

Comment: Попробуйте на клиенте разбирать DTO, а не сущность. Имею в виду, к примеру th:field указывать поле Вашего DTO, а не сущности.

Answer (score 1):

Для валидации строки можно использовать аннотацию `@Length(max = 255)`

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class AuthRq extends BaseRq {

  @JsonProperty("username")
  @NotEmpty
  @Length(max = 255)
  private String username;

  @JsonProperty("password")
  @NotEmpty
  @Length(max = 255)
  private String password;

}



// Controller ==================================


@RequestMapping(value = AUTH_URL, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<AuthRs> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody @Valid AuthRq authenticationRequest) throws Exception {
    ....
    }
```